# PostgreSQL subquery - calculating average of lagged values

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, subquery, lag

I am looking at Sales Rates by month, and was able to query the 1st table. I am quite new to PostgreSQL and am trying to figure out how I can query the second (I had to do the 2nd one in Excel for now)
I have the current Sales Rate and I would like to compare it to the Sales Rate 1 and 2 months ago, as an averaged rate.

[image]

I am not asking for an answer how exactly to solve it because this is not the point of getting better, but just for hints for functions to use that are specific to PostgreSQL. What I am trying to calculate is the 2 month average in the 2nd table based on the lagged values of the 2nd table. Thanks!

Here is the query for the 1st table:

```
with t1 as
    (select date,
            count(sales)::numeric/count(poss_sales) as SR_1M_before 
            from data
    where date between '2019-07-01' and '2019-11-30'
            group by 1),
     t2 as
    (select date,
            count(sales)::numeric/count(poss_sales) as SR_2M_before 
            from data
    where date between '2019-07-01' and '2019-10-31'
            group by 1)
select t0.date,
       count(t0.sales)::numeric/count(t0.poss_sales) as Sales_Rate 
       t1.SR_1M_before,
       t2.SR_2M_before
        from data as t0
        left join t1 on t0.date=t1.date
        left join t2 on t0.date=t1.date
        where date between '2019-07-01' and '2019-12-31'
group by 1,3,4
order by 1;
```

Comment: Please show us your current query.

Comment: The "two months average" can be calculated with a window function: `avg(sales_rate) over (order by "date" range between '2 month' preceding and current row)` if you always have a row for each month, you can also use `rows between 2 preceding and current row`)

Comment: @GMB: added my current query

Answer (score 0):

As commented by a_horse_with_no_name, you can use window functions to take the average of the two previous monthes with a range clause:

```
select 
    date,
    count(sales)::numeric/count(poss_sales) as Sales_Rate,
    avg(count(sales)::numeric/count(poss_sales)) over(
        order by date
        rows between '2 month' preceding and '1 month' preceding
    ) Sales_Rate,
    count(sales)::numeric/count(poss_sales) as Sales_Rate 
        - avg(count(sales)::numeric/count(poss_sales)) over(
            order by date
            rows between '2 month' preceding and '1 month' preceding
        ) PercentDeviation
from data
where date between '2019-07-01' and '2019-12-31'
group by date
order by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a bit confusing -- it would be less confusing if you had decimal places (that is, 58% being the average of 57% and 58% is not obvious).

Because you want to have `NULL` values on the first two rows, I'm going to calculate the values using `sum()` and `count()`:

```
with q as (
      <whatever generates the data you have shown>
     )
select q.*,
       (sum(sales_rate) over (order by date
                              rows between 2 preceding and 1 preceding
                             ) /
        nullif(count(*) over (order by date
                              rows between 2 preceding and 1 preceding
                             )
       ) as two_month_average
from q;
```

You could also express this using `case` and `avg()`:

```
select q.*,
       (case when row_number() over (order by date) > 2)
             then avg(sales_rate) over (order by date
                                        rows between 2 preceding and 1 preceding
                                       )
        end) as two_month_average
from q;
```